# Whole string is numerical, but ignore all zeros if at the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following to make sure a string is only numbers:

```
myStr.match(/^[0-9]*$/g);
```

But I'm looking to refine it by ignoring any zeroes at the beginning unless it's the only digit or just returning 0 if it's all zeroes.

I'd like something like this:

```
myStr = "0"; //--> match = 0
myStr = "00"; //--> match = 0
myStr = "10"; //--> match = 10
myStr = "05"; //--> match = 5
myStr = "000007"; //--> match = 7
```

I imagine the second line here makes things more tricky since I'm also checking if there are only zeroes. Perhaps this too much for regex alone. I've found plenty of examples of checking if it starts with zero and skipping it, but I'm having difficulty finding something that grabs the rest of the number and just ignore the zeroes.

EDIT: As far as parseInt() goes, unfortunately, this is an After Effects expression which uses an older version of ECMAScript. Something like parseInt("010") returns 8 (octal).

Comment: Could you use parseInt()? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: @DanielGale's comment is the best way to go about this. Alternatively, using regex, you can do `s.match(/^0*(\d+)$/)[1]`

Comment: Why use regex here when `parseInt` does what you need?

Comment: `/[1-9][0-9]*/` ?

Comment: @JonasW. doesn't work on `0`

Comment: add an `|0` to that

Comment: @DanielGale: `parseInt` has its own issues, such as `parseInt("0123abc", 10)` being `123`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but isn't that the expected output according to the OP's information?

Comment: @ctwheels: .....no? The regex clearly disallows non-digits.

Comment: *"...by ignoring any zeroes at the beginning..."* define "ignoring"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess there isn't enough information to determine proper output on strings with other characters. For instance, what should be the outcome of `0.1`?

Comment: maybe my comment was a bit too little information on what i mean - `/([1-9][0-9]*|0)$/`

Comment: /([1-9]\d*)|0/ should work fine

Comment: Re: parseInt - Unfortunately, this is an After Effects expression which uses older version of ECMAScript. parseInt("010") returns as 8.

Comment: The comment from @ctwheels looks to be simple and clean, but if you don't *need* regex, would `s => Number(s)` be enough?  Or if you want a string output, `s => String(Number(s))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a lookbehind (coming to JavaScript soon!), you'll need a capture group or other logic in addition to the regex.

Here's the capture group version:

```
/^0*(\d+)$/
```

*(Many thanks to [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) for pointing out my earlier one with `0|[1-9]\d*` could be shortened to just `\d+` [since we've consumed any leading zeros except enough to satisfy `\d+` with the leading `0*`]!)*

Example:

```js
var rex = /^0*(\d+)$/;
function test(myStr, expect) {
  var match = myStr.match(rex);
  var val = match ? match[1] : null;
  console.log(myStr, val, val === expect ? "Good" : "ERROR");
}
test("0", "0");
test("00", "0");
test("10", "10");
test("05", "5");
test("000007", "7");
```

Comment: `/^0*(0|[1-9]\d*)$/` can be shortened to `/^0*(\d+)$/` since `0*` is greedy.

Comment: @ctwheels: Nice one! Of course, since we've consumed leading 0s with the first bit. Silly me. :-)

Comment: No problem, actually, you don't even need the `0|` now

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks to you both.

Comment: @ctwheels: *slaps head repeatedly*